# Unmapped POJO used as class type in a native query's result exception

Tags: java, sql, jpa, pojo

Given a class:

```
class MyClass {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
```

and code like so:

```
Query q = getEntityManager()
          .createNativeQuery('select a, b from table', MyClass.class);
```

It throws an exception. My solution is to add

```
'' as c
```

in the sql. However, the c in MyClass is a variable that I intend to put some calculated value into, and that c does not have any real mapping to the table, so the solution just puts the c with a blank value...

My question is, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark c as @Transient so that it is not mapped.